# Fault tolerance by using two IP with two interfaces

Tags: ip, arp

I would like to have a fault-tolerant setup for http requests. For brevity, let's assume we have a very simple Web-service and there is no difference which server responses.

So I will have the following setup (all three are in the same LAN):

```
Upstream Gateway:
eth0 - 10.0.0.1

Server1:
eth0 - 10.0.0.10
eth1 - 10.0.0.11

Server2:
eth0 - 10.0.0.10
eth1 - 10.0.0.11
```

Looks stupid? Nope, not at all. When the IP-packet hits gateway, it looks for level 2 address, so it makes ARP request. The response contains hardware address (it will be hardware address of Server1 or Server2, the fastest wins), and the ARP response will be cached, but for a short time.

Now Server1 is down. Only Server2 responses with the hardware address, and everything goes as usual. So in case of failure I have

Any precautions?

Comment: Have you tried this because I doubt it's going to work as splendidly as you think it is.

Comment: Would interface trunking: http://www.linuxhorizon.ro/bonding.html achieve the same results ?

Comment: @joeqwerty Well, I could test it in my VMs under VirtualBox and post the results here, but it will work for sure.

Comment: @LowKianSeong bonding has nothing to do with fault tolerance. Bonding allows combine two network interfaces and use them as one. What I want is a fault tolerance with almost zero downtime.

Comment: If you know that it will work for sure then why are you asking your question? It sounds like you've got everything figured out. I say go forth and implement it.

Comment: I doubt that it will work well: what happens if your apr entry expires during a long transfer and the other host is faster on new request? Suddenly your switch will route traffic to another port and the box there doesn't really know what to do with it. IMHO its not good to try to solve problems on layer2, that belong in a higher layer. HA is usually done via moving IP's (see pacemaker for this), Loadbalancers or DNS round robin - this topic it to wide for a comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although what you've come up with is clever, one issue would be that routing of the packets could switch back and forth between the two machines arbitrarily.  I emphasize *packets*, not TCP connections.  So randomly TCP connections would be reset as the routing bounces back and forth.

For a pure single-packet UDP service, you might have a little bit better chance of it working.

However, there are mechanisms at play designed to prevent you from having the same IP on multiple NICs on the same network.  You'd have to find ways around these safeguards.

The approach I take is to have an IP address that the two machines will negotiate.  Call it a "virtual IP".  The primary machine will normally have this IP added to it as an alias.  The secondary machine would monitor the primary machine and takeover the IP when it detects the primary is down.

The secondary would take the IP by adding an alias then issuing a specific arping to let the network know things have moved.

You can also switch roles at any time by removing the alias from the first machine then adding it to the second as described above.

Comment: Thanks. I've completely forgotten about TCP session establishment. Will use IPVS instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered Pacemaker or Keepalived. Neither is capable of the kind of (dare I say) round robin fault tolerance you are purposing, in so far as only one server will be available under an IP at any time. But this kind of configuration allows for more involved HTTP transactions. What you are describing will possibly lead to the clients receiving the same data from different servers are different times in a session.

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To be frank, yes it does look *bad*.  But we're all here to learn.  If you are working on a windows platform you should look into something like network load balancing (link below) for fault tolerance and performance.  I'm guessing there are similar things for linux.  I've never used NLB personally but have always had one or more load balancers sit in front the of http servers to provide fault tolerance and load balancing.  Granted you are trying to gain a high availability with your setup, but the gateway is still going to be a single point of failure.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831698.aspx

Answer (score 0):

That will just not work as you think because both machines are on the same broadcast domain. While a stale ARP entry triggers an ARP broadcast request and related unicast reply, IP assignment triggers ARP broadcast probes and announcements. So at least two bad things will happen :

- IP assignment on the second rig will fail because of ARP probing.
- You could end up with the IP locked or partially/completely unassigned as a result of IP address defense mechanisms.

Read [RFC 5227](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5227) for the glory details.